# Point for minimum distance

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Find the coordinates of the point P on the line $d : 2x − y − 5 = 0$ for which the sum
$AP + PB$ is minimum, when $A(−7, 1)$ and $B(−5, 5)$. Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: I would start by parametrisizing the set of points; for example
$$
\begin{cases}
x =& t \\
y =& 2t-5
\end{cases}
$$
Then, for a given value of $t$, formulate the expression for the sum $AP+PB$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [minimal distance between two points and point on a plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258951/minimal-distance-between-two-points-and-point-on-a-plane)

Comment: You have enough reputation to know that posting a problem with no effort is unacceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Segment $AB$ is parallel to the line. Therefore $AP+PB$ is minimum if $\vec{P}=\frac{\vec{A}+\vec{B}}{2}+t\{2\hat{i}-\hat{j}\}$.

Substitute this to the equation line to obtain $t=4$. Thus $\vec{P}=\{2\hat{i}-\hat{j}\}$

Comment: This is an interesting vector formula. How'd you derive it, considering the restriction of $P$ having to be on a specific line?

Comment: @Plato it is derived from the fact that the segment is parallel to the line, think about triangle $APB$ as triangle with fixed base $AB$ and fixed height. $AP+PB$ is minimum if the triangle is isosceles i.e. $P$ is a point somewhere along the line perpendicular to $AB$ and through midpoint of $AB$

Comment: Makes total sense. But that thing about minimum distance from an isosceles triangle, is that a property in geometry because I just stumbled upon that fact with my own answer.

Comment: @Plato think of a point $Q$ on $AB$ such that $PQ$ is perpendicular to $AB$. $AP+BP=\sqrt{PQ^{2}+AQ^{2}}+\sqrt{PQ^{2}+BQ^{2}}$ with $AQ+BQ$ is fixed and $PQ$ fixed. some inequality later, it is minimum when $AQ=BQ$ i.e. the triangle is isosceles

Comment: Nice. I'll have to keep that one in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a set of points on the line $\text{d}$ is given by:

$$\text{P}\left(x,\text{y}\right)=\text{P}\left(x,2x-5\right)\tag1$$

Using the [distance formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#Geometry), we can find:

- $$\left|\text{AP}\right|=\sqrt{\left(x-\left(-7\right)\right)^2+\left(2x-5-1\right)^2}\tag2$$
- $$\left|\text{BP}\right|=\sqrt{\left(x-\left(-5\right)\right)^2+\left(2x-5-5\right)^2}\tag3$$

Now, find:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\left|\text{AP}\right|+\left|\text{BP}\right|\right)=0\tag4$$

Which will give $x=2$, and $\text{y}=2\cdot2-5=-1$ so $\text{P}\left(2,-1\right)$.

---

Using my comment, you can see:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sqrt{\left(x-\left(-7\right)\right)^2+\left(2x-5-1\right)^2}\right)=\frac{\left(x-\left(-7\right)\right)+2\left(2x-5-1\right)}{\sqrt{\left(x-\left(-7\right)\right)^2+\left(2x-5-1\right)^2}}\tag5$$

And:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sqrt{\left(x-\left(-5\right)\right)^2+\left(2x-5-5\right)^2}\right)=\frac{\left(x-\left(-5\right)\right)+2\left(2x-5-5\right)}{\sqrt{\left(x-\left(-5\right)\right)^2+\left(2x-5-5\right)^2}}\tag5$$

Comment: Yes, I did this, but from the derivative form I don't know how to find that x = 2.

Comment: @Gaboru it is not hard to show that: $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sqrt{f(x)^2+y(x)^2}\right)=\frac{f(x)f'(x)+y(x)y'(x)}{\sqrt{f(x)^2+y(x)^2}}$$ Besides that, we know that: $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(f(x)+y(x)\right)=f'(x)+y'(x)$$ And: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(ax+b\right)=a$$

Comment: I got that:$$\frac{5x-5}{\sqrt(5x^2-10x+85)} + \frac{5x-15}{\sqrt(5x^2-30x+125)}=0 $$ but I don't know how to find the solution from here

Comment: I did the derivative but I don't know how to solve the equation to get that x=2

Answer (score 0):

Any point $P$ on that line would have a general form of $(x, 2x-5)$

Then you would evaluate the following:

$|PA|^2=(x+7)^2+(2x-6)^2$

$|PB|^2=(x+5)^2+(2x-10)^2$

Now the question asks us to minimize $PA+PB$, which would involve the square roots of these signs. But here's a better idea.

$\operatorname{min}(|PA|+|PB|) \equiv \operatorname{min}\left ((|PA|+|PB|)^2 \right)$

$\equiv \operatorname{min}(PA^2+PB^2+2 \cdot |PA| \cdot |PB|)$

$\equiv \operatorname{min}(PA^2+PB^2)$

So we just minimize the sum of their squares.

Which in this case totals to:

$10x^2-40x+210=10(x^2-4x+21)$

This is a parabola so finding it's minimum should give us the minimum for that abscissa. Doing that:

$2x-4=0 \implies x=2$

So the point $P$ that gives minimum expression is $(2, -1)$. Peace.

Fun fact: $PAB$ is isosceles, which if I knew geometrically was true I would've gone a different route, of making an isosceles triangle instead.

Comment: I don't understad how did you play with that minimum...that 2PA*PB dissapeared

Comment: It didn't entirely disappear. The point was that the sum is minimal, the square of the sum is minimal and thus every term created has to be at it's minimum. It's the beauty of having no negative signs, or at least crafting your way out of one. And I don't have the time to differentiate a square root function.