# Sum of distances of a variable point from two fixed points.

Tags: optimization, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Given that $A\equiv(4,2)$ and $B\equiv(2,4)$, find a point $P$ on the line $3x+2y+10=0$ such that $PA+PB$ is minimum.

---

**My attempt:**

In $\triangle PAB$,

$$PA+PB\ge AB$$ Hence, the minimum value should be $AB=2\sqrt 2$. But in the solution point $P$ is given as $\displaystyle(-\frac{14}{5}, -\frac{4}{5})$ from which $PA+PB$ comes out to be $10\sqrt 2$.

Where am I going wrong? Help is requested!

Comment: The question you have to ask yourself is: Is it possible to find a point P on the line such that PA+PB=2sqrt(2)? Make a graph of the situation in desmos. The graph is essential.

Comment: You have a geometric construction to find $P$ https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2259031/399263

Answer (score 3):

This is an instance of Heron's problem and this is a proof without words:

[image]

Comment: $@$Jack D'Aurizio, thanks for your solution. But what I want to know is why can't we use the triangle inequality here?

Comment: @Doubtnut In this figure E should actually denoote the required oint  P. now you see if you take any point on ED line as P, the PA+PB >AB equality will never satisfy. in fact PA+PB >>>AB. But if you take E  as P, then A'P=AP so AP+BP=A'B+BP=A'B will satisfy if you choose any other point on this line say P' then see very clearly that A'P+BP'> A'B (triabgular law. so A'B gives the the required min. When A and B are are on opposite side, AB will provide the min. and P will be the intersection of the given line L and AB.

Answer (score 2):

If $A(4,2), B(2,4)$ are on the same side of the line not on the same line $L=3x+2y+10=0.$
Let the image of $A$ about $L$ be $A'$, then $A'P=AP$ then $AP+BP=A'P+BP$ is minimum
when $A',P,B$ are collinear and $PA;+PB=A'B$
Image $A'(x',y')$ is obtained as
$$\frac{x'-4}{3}=\frac{y'-2}{2}=-2\frac{12+4+10}{9+4}\implies x'=-8, y'=-6$$
The equation of $A'B$ is $x-y=-2$ and the required point $P$ is thr intersection of this line with $L$, we get $P(-14/5,-4/5)$ and $AP+BP \ge A'B=10\sqrt{2}$

Comment: But what's wrong with the triangle inequality which I used?

Comment: @Dooubtnut this idea $PA+PB \ge AB$ works if points $A,B$ are on the opposite sides of the given line. Here bot A and B are on the same side of the line.

Comment: `@Dr Zafar Ahmed DSc`, I got your point. But when they are on same side, triangle is still forming, so why can't we use it. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A'$ be symmetric to $A$ respect to $l:3x+2y+10=0$.

Thus, $BA'\cap l=\{P\}$.

I got, since $AA'\perp l,$ we obtain: $$AA'\cap L=\{(-2,-2)\},$$ $$A'(-8,-6),$$  the equation of $BA'$ it's $y=x+2$ and $$P\left(-\frac{14}{5},-\frac{4}{5}\right).$$

Comment: But sir, why can't we use the triangle inequality?

Comment: @Doubtnut No, we can. My solution based on the triangle inequality. The different it that in my solution the minimum occurs for $P\left(-\frac{14}{5},-\frac{4}{5}\right).$ But in your reasoning the value $2\sqrt2$ does not occur.

Comment: That's actually my doubt. According to me, the method I used is errorless then why the answers are not matching. I just want anyone to point out my mistake.

Comment: @Doubtnut I explained it already. See my previous comment. Your way is wrong because a value $2\sqrt2$ does not occur, which says that $2\sqrt2$ is not a minimal value of the sum. Also,  we can say that $PA+PB\geq0,$ but the value $0$ does not occur, which says that $0$ is not a minimal value of the sum.

Comment: How do we check which values can not occur or where will be the actual minimum without the reflection method?

Comment: @Doubtnut Without reflection we can use derivative. Also, we can use Minkowski, but for to find a solution we need to know the answer, which is not so fair.

Answer (score 0):

If you draw the graph, you will understand Michael's argument. To find the coordinate of $A^\prime$ quickly, you can use the formula for the distance from a point $(a,b)$ to line $Ax+By+C=0$ as follows:
$$d=\frac{|Aa+Bb+C|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}.$$
Suppose the coordinate of $A^\prime$ is $(a, b)$, then
$$\frac{-(3a+2b+10)}{\sqrt{3^2+2^2}}=\frac{3(4)+2(2)+10}{\sqrt{3^2+2^2}}.$$
The reason of adding a negative sign to the left-hand side is because $A^\prime$ lies under the line $3x+2y+10=0$.
To solve $a$ and $b$, you need to add another equation from the fact that $AA^\prime$ is perpendicular to the line $3x+2y+10=0$.
$$\frac{b-2}{a-4}\cdot \frac{-3}{2}=-1.$$